# Restructure a css file so that each selector exists only once

Tags: css

I don't really know the best way to ask but I am wondering if there is any way to turn this:

```css
li,
li>h3 {
    display: flex
}

li {
    height: 48px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 8px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

into this for an entire file:

```css
li {
    display: flex;
    height: 48px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 8px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden
}

li>h3 {
    display: flex
}
```

Comment: Yes it could be done using JS, though you might find it a tall order... look into the CSSStyelSheets obj... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Comment: another great reference for the CSSOM => https://css-tricks.com/an-introduction-and-guide-to-the-css-object-model-cssom/